# Swift 2 unrecognized selector in tapgesture

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7-beta4

I recently started to update my app to Swift 2.0, but I've run into a problem that has a hundred different answers on SO, none of which seemed to be related to my problem.

(This worked before updating the application to Swift 2.0), but I havn't been able to find any changes made to tap gesture recognisers?

Here's the full error I'm getting:

> [Stocks.SidePanelViewController proFormulaTapGesture]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14f06ae00
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Stocks.SidePanelViewController proFormulaTapGesture]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14f06ae00'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
> (0x1830904d0 0x197afff9c 0x1830971ec 0x183094188 0x182f9920c 0x188c3c58c 0x188899b50 0x18872d104 0x188c3bc30 0x1886ed28c 0x1886eb3ac 0x18872b088 0x18872a5ec 0x1886fb908 0x1886f9fac 0x183047d6c 0x183047800 0x183045500 0x182f75280 0x18e0ec0cc 0x188762df8 0x100158184 0x1983428b8)
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

It's a simple tap gesture. But it seems to not recognize the selector anymore.

Here's the code I use to set up the recognizer:

```
let proFormulaTap = UITapGestureRecognizer()

proFormulaTap.addTarget(self, action:"proFormulaTapGesture")
proFormulaView.addGestureRecognizer(proFormulaTap)
```

Here's the function I'm trying to run:

```
func proFormulaTapGesture() throws {
        print("proFormulaTapGesture")
        selectView(proFormulaView)
        selectedMenuItem = 0
        Formula = 1
        menuTabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
        navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "BASIC FORMULA"
        try (menuTabBarController.viewControllers as! [SuggestionsViewController])[0].loadSuggestions()
    }
```

However since it never prints "proFormulaTapGesture" in the console. I definitely think the error occurs before the function. Also suggested by the error mentioning the selector.

Obviously try/catch has been added to the function since the update to Swift 2.0, but nothing has been changed in the setup of the tapGestureRecognizer.

I tried removing the "throws" and try from the function, but the problem perists. I also tried making a button instead of a tap gesture recognizer. But I'm still getting the same error, suggesting it might be a problem with the selector (function) and not the tap gesture / button. However all my other buttons in my app works just fine?

I also tried to rename the selector/function, and the tap gesture recognizer. Still the same.

The original Code was programmed in Swift, not Obj-C. The throws and try, was added during Apple's code conversion to Swift 2.0

Any help to why this is suddenly broken would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you just try commenting that try statement and removing that 'throws' - simply to check if that is causing the issue?

Comment: @nshebbar I just tried that, still the same error. Thank you for the suggestion though! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Hmm, OK, also try changing the name of the function also.

Comment: @nshebbar I just updated my post with that and a couple of other attempts I've made to fix it. Yeah :(

Comment: Try fully qualified function that also takes gestureRecogniser as argument: func proFormulaTapGesture(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) throws .   and to match - proFormulaTap.addTarget(self, action:"proFormulaTapGesture:")

Comment: @nshebbar I tried making a new function that only had a print in it. Still the same issue.

Comment: `@objc func proFormulaTapGesture()` & [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-ID0).

Comment: @robertvojta It's not Obj-C code.

Comment: @MarkL but the _UIKit_ is ... `UITapGestureRecognizer` (Obj-C) is calling your Swift code.

Comment: Forgot to mention that `@objc` is required when the method is `private`. These are not automatically exposed to Objective-C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue may be that UIKit does not know how to call a selector that `throws`, at least in this context.

Remember that UIKit will be calling this function in response to a tap action. It is not accustomed to calling a function that `throws`; obviously the `throw` must alter the method's call signature as far as the Objective-C runtime is concerned. Beyond that, if your function `proFormulaTapGesture` did throw an error, what would UIKit do with the error even if it could catch it?

I'm not sure where you added `do`/`try`/`catch`. But unless it was inside your action function `proFormulaTapGesture`, I do not see how it could be relevant. I believe that you will need to implement the `try`/`catch` error handling inside `proFormulaTapGesture`, so that it effectively swallows the error, so that `proFormulaTapGesture` does not throw.

I just created a quick test project myself and found that a `throw`ing target action gives the same "Unrecognized selector" error you got:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tapper = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didClick")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapper!)
}

func didClick() throws {
    print("did click")
}
```

> 2015-07-27 00:16:43.260 Test1[71047:54227175] -[Test1.ViewController didClick]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000c5010
>
> ...

I believe you will need to rework your code to handle the error internally in your action function so that it does not throw - something like this:

```
func proFormulaTapGesture() {
    print("proFormulaTapGesture")
    selectView(proFormulaView)
    selectedMenuItem = 0
    Formula = 1
    menuTabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
    navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "BASIC FORMULA"
    do {
        try (menuTabBarController.viewControllers as! [SuggestionsViewController])[0].loadSuggestions()
    } catch {
        // Handle the error here somehow
    }
}
```

If you are unable to handle the error within `proFormulaTapGesture`, you'll have to be more creative with passing it out of the function (think NSNotification, etc...).

---

To be clear, I created a new Single View iOS application in Xcode 7 beta 4, and used this exact code as my ViewController. No other changes. The app compiles and works just fine in the iOS simulator.

@robertvojta also points out that if `didTap` below is marked `private`, `@objc` is also required to avoid a dynamic dispatch crash.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var tapper: UITapGestureRecognizer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tapper = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTap")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapper!)
    }

    func didTap() {
        print("did Tap")
    }

}
```

(Note I also tested on an OS X project, which is the code I used earlier in the answer).

Comment: _I'm not 100% sure, I believe, ..._ Did you test your code? You have to use `@objc` otherwise you'll still get _Unrecognized selector ..._.

Comment: ill try this, but as mentioned in the post, I already tried making a simple function only containing a print, that didn't throw. And it still didn't work. But I'll try again to make sure :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yeah I'm still getting the same error with your edit.

Comment: I figured it out. And this answer was right, despite my last error. After I cleaned the project, deleted old log files and such. Restarted Xcode and ran it again, this worked fine. :) Thank you so much!

Comment: @user2194039 deleted my answer. To make your answer better, just add note about `@objc`, which is needed when the method is private (these are not exposed to ObjC by default). `private func didTap()` will not work without `@objc`.

Comment: @robertvojta Thanks and I added a little more code to show clearly exactly what I ran that worked. And really, like I mentioned earlier, `@objc` was my first thought as well. I was using language like "_not 100% sure_" because my tested code worked, but I don't have any documentation to back it up.

Comment: @robertvojta I revised the note about `@objc` based on your comment (I also tested it and found it to be spot on ;) ). Thanks for that bit of info regarding `private` and `@objc`; that does explain some things for me.

Comment: @user2194039 safe approach is probably to mark all these dynamic things with `@objc` even if they're exposed automatically to Objective-C. Doesn't hurt and if you mark it with `private` in the future, it will not cause crash. Also it acts like a tag/comment - be aware, this one is going to be used from Objective-C framework, ...

Comment: Just FYI - Release notes quote: _Declarations marked private are not exposed to the Objective-C runtime if not otherwise annotated. IB outlets, IB actions, and Core Data managed properties remain exposed to Objective-C whatever their access level. If you need a private method or property to be callable from Objective-C (such as for an older API that uses a selector-based callback), add the @objc attribute to the declaration explicitly._

Comment: @robertvojta Agreed 1000x and now I know why. Thanks!